# DAX calculation - Count of ids for all previous years than the selected year in the dropdown

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

How to get count of all the previous years than the selected year in the dropdown with multiple filter conditions.

```
                  CALCULATE(
                    COUNT(current_ar[request_id]),  
                     FILTER(current_ar, 
                   current_ar[Fiscal_Year] < SELECTEDVALUE(current_ar[Fiscal_Year])))
```

syntax is not working as expected. I want all the previous years count while the selection is made on the year dropdown. How the syntax can be written above??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ALL(...)`

```
Your Measure = CALCULATE(
    COUNT(current_ar[request_id]),  
    FILTER(
      ALL(current_ar[Fiscal_Year]),
      current_ar[Fiscal_Year] < SELECTEDVALUE(current_ar[Fiscal_Year])
    )
  )
```